why Wincc got syntax error in vba comiler to create object when using as object type?
In wincc v8.0, when Defining an object like "HMIPictureWindow" object by this code in vba:
Dim objPictureWindow As HMIPictureWindow

vba compiler get syntax error. but by deleting  'As HMIPictureWindow', Not any more error.
but i need to define that object so its need the code exist.

You need to add a reference to the object library in the VBE if early binding is used. Microsoft documentation:

Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)

